Is Red Productivity (not inflation) driving up the cost of living?
Cost of living goes up when productivity goes up faster than wages, because the proceeds of increased productivity are then used to force the middle class out of the housing market, driving up the price of housing, driving up the prices on farmland so food is more expensive while wages stay the same.  The productivity AI is creating is being used to drive up to prices instead of wages.
Productivity can drive up prices instead of wages if salaries do not increase with productivity.
Black productivity has wages increase with productivity instead of prices. It is called black because it puts the middle class in a better position often called “the black.”
Red Productivity has prices increase with productivity instead of wages.  It is called red because it puts the middle class in the red through raising prices not wages.
Brown productivity has prices and wages rise at the same time.
Red and Black productivity are both examples of successful class warfare with a class winner and a class looser.
Only Balanced Brown Productivity is class neutral.
Claim: Red productivity is more causal to the cost of living crisis than inflation.
There are two solutions to red productivity demonstrated since the 1970s.
Solution 1
Stop being so productive. Retruning to the productivity level of the 1970s solves the cost of living crisis as the proceeds of productivity gains since then have been used to drive up prices while wages have stayed the same.
Solution 2
Stop being so stingy. Red productivity is stinginess. Keeping all the proceeds of increasing productivity away from the workers.
Claim to debate:
Red Productivity not inflation is causing the cost of living crisis.
